# Additional Borders on windows in Awesome

Tags: window, gtk, awesome-wm, border, gtk-windows

I have an Arch Linux 64-bit install running Awesome-WM,
However I seem to have a problem with the borders on opened windows(Generally in gtk apps)
Also I have Compton Composition Manager running

Somewhat like this:
 [image: Picture]

Does anyone know what is causing this ??
And how to remove it ??

Comment: @Cornelius I'm sorry but my rep. won't let me add images..And I unaware of it rejected you're edit without knowing I'm sorry could you please help me ?? Sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome WM itself doesn't cause this issue, however gtk+ does...
Thanks to google+ user Thomas Berryhill who indicated me to add these lines to my gtk.css

~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css :

.window-frame { box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px @wm_border; margin: 0px; }﻿

[Voila @Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09bUz.png)